How to insert a shortcode into a WooCommerce PHP file?
Here below, is an existing function which is called in woocommerece-integration.php file to display the add to cart button in product cards on any WordPress page. I have a wishlist plugin which gives a shortcode and I need to display that icon before the $content:
        // Add add_to_cart btn wrapper (products loop)
        $adc = '<div class="card_bot"> 
        <div class="vamtam-add-to-cart-wrap shrt">'
            . $content .    
        '</div></div>';

        return apply_filters( 'vamtam_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', $adc );
    }
}

The main goal is to get the wishlist icon on left and add to cart button on right in same row later which I can handle with CSS but both the buttons should be within same wrapper class card_bot which is my main goal.
This is my shortcode: [wlfmc_add_to_wishlist]
I have tried :

echo do_shortcode("[wlfmc_add_to_wishlist]");
php echo do_shortcode tag as well

Both seem to give errors and are breaking my PHP file or displaying the shortcode as a string. What is the correct way to do it?

From your provided code, try inserting do_shortcode() without echo, using . concatenation operator, like:
    $adc = '<div class="card_bot"> 
        <div class="vamtam-add-to-cart-wrap shrt">'
         . do_shortcode("[wlfmc_add_to_wishlist]") . $content .    
        '</div></div>';
    return apply_filters( 'vamtam_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', $adc );

It should work.

In order to achieve what you want I think you should use hook.
There are two types of hooks :

action: mainly used to add custom traitment(s) during a certain event
filter: mainly used to modify elements

So in your case, you should use a filter because what you basically want is to modify how the add to cart button is displayed (aka add a wrapper and your shortcode).
I suggest you search in the woo hook reference to find the right hook for your case (maybe: woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link) :
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html
And to add the plugin's shortcode in your callback method, the correct way is:
echo do_shortcode('[wlfmc_add_to_wishlist]');

